# Wifi driver not working in LENOVO Z51

Tags: 14.04, atheros

Output of  `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3826]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0041] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
04:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] [1002:6820] (rev ff)
```

Comment: Few months back, I had used this post  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2296057     to fix it. It was working well until I update my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to upgrade the kernel to 4.4. It supports this adapter without adding backports.

Otherwise you will have to re-install backports after each kernel upgrade.

You can do it by running in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Your Wi-Fi should work after a reboot.